# Optimizing this method (HashSet.RemoveWhere performance issue)

Tags: c#, .net, hash-map

I have the following method:

```
public static HashSet<PathDetails> GetDeletedPaths(HashSet<PathDetails> old, HashSet<PathDetails> current)
{
    var deleted = new HashSet<PathDetails>(old);
    deleted.RemoveWhere(x => current.Any(y => y.Path == x.Path));
    return deleted;
}
```

`PathDetails` is a struct that, among other things, contains `Path` of type `String`. This method takes the longest in my application and I was wondering if there were any good ways of improving its performance. These hash sets are used elsewhere in a more hashset-friendly way, so the method must take in two sets and return a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `RemoveWhere()` method together with the `Any()` method you should consider to just use [`ExceptWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
public static HashSet<PathDetails> GetDeletedPaths(HashSet<PathDetails> old, HashSet<PathDetails> current)
{
    var deleted = new HashSet<PathDetails>(old);
    deleted.ExceptWith(current);
    return deleted;
}
```

Your approach calls for each item in `deleted` the `Any()` of `current` whereas `ExceptWith()` just calls for each item in `current` the `Remove()` method of `deleted`.

Comment: This approach is still problematic because the structure contains more than just `Path`, and I only want to match on the `Path` of each `PathDetails` structure, not all of its members.

Comment: Then add an `IEqualityComparer` which only targets the `Path` property.

Comment: So basically, `var deleted = new HashSet<PathDetails>(old, _pathOnlyEqualityComparer);` and (after calling `ExceptWith` on the other hash sets) I would `return new HashSet<PathDetails>(deleted);` in order to revert to the default equality comparer for `PathDetails` for this object? The performance boost is excellent, by the way. Thank you!

Comment: I also implemented my equality comparer's `Equals` method using `return (x.Path.Equals(y.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));` in case anyone is interested, as ordinal is what I care about and it is much more performant in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a set containing the paths in `current`. Then instead of adding and removing `PathDetails`, just add them instead.

```
var paths = new HashSet<string>(current.Select(x => x.Path));
return new HashSet<PathDetails>(old.Where(x => !paths.Contains(x.Path)));
```

---

Since `PathDetails` is a struct, make sure you're overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, as it can lead to [improved performance](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Struct-Equality-Performance-in-C.aspx).